# Trouble filling 2D array with values obtained from method

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble filling a matrix with values I get by iterating through a method. I want to use a 3x3 matrix and then fill it with the values I obtain by iterating my method from 0 to 8. My idea was a for-loop but it does not work unfortunately. I would be glad if someone could help or has a link where I can look that up.

```
int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
  for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
    for(int a = 0; a < 9; a++) {
      matrix[i][j] = fields.get(a).getSign().getFieldValue();
    }       
  }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong.

The way I understood your question was you want to fill the matrix like this:

```
012
345
678
```

In that case you can do the first 2 forloops and add some maths, to get the correct numbers on every position:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
    matrix[i][j] = i * matrix[i].length + j;
  }
}
```

The way this works is for every row (i) you multiply the rownumber by the rows length (the number of columns) and add the current column to it

Comment: Oh yes, that seems to work. I just substituted my "a "variable from my solution through your solution with the i mulitplication. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through a two dimensional field (e.g. a matrix), you can use two for loops:

```
int dimension = 3;
int [][] matrix = new int [dimension][dimension];

for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
   for ( int j = 0; j < dimension; j++){
      matrix[i][j] = fields.get(i).get(j);
   }
}
```

I don't exactly know how you want to retrieve the values, but your current call looks suspicious to say the least :-)
It will simply assign the same value to all ints in column `j`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simulate your loop, this is what it looks like

```
i -> 0
    j -> 0
        matrix[0][0] -> loop over all values from field
```

this way you would be putting the `fields.get(8)` into each index in your matrix.

@Alan's answers show how to properly loop and fill a 2d matrix from a 1d matrix